# Windows Azure Storage for WordPress plugin not listing blob containers

Tags: plugins

I've just installed wordpress 4.8.2, set it up for multi-site, and deployed the Windows Azure Storage for WordPress plugin version 4.0.2.

In a new sub-site, I'm trying to configure the plugin settings.

I enter the account name and key, but the Default Storage Container dropdown does not contain any items, so I can't choose any containers.  It doesn't even show me the option of creating a new container.

[image]

It will let me save without only entering a name and key.  And the other odd behaviour is that if I go back to the page after saving, I only see half of it:

[image]

I can't tell if this is an issue with how I set up the storage account and blob container (I did it through Azure CLI) or if it's an incompatability between the WordPress version and the plugin.

Comment: If you are going to down vote, can you please have the curtesy to say why?

Comment: I haven't, but third-party plugin questions are off topic, that's why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is to install the php xml package:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml <br/>
sudo service php7.0-fpm restart <br/>
sudo service nginx restart
```

I discovered the actual problem one of the log files:

```
2017/10/16 22:14:07 [error] 14850#14850: *1090 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function simplexml_load_string() in ...
```

Turns out that function is supplied by php-xml